# virtuemart implementation in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a query. I have installed virtuemart component for joomla 1.5. Now if in my website, the stock is not available, then is it possible to redirect to some other ecommerce site where that particular product is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think native virtuemart component wont allow it. As far as I know virtuemart component have some options such as Disable buy now button if stocks are not available. But I didn't see such an option you are requesting.

But if you really want to do it you can do it by creating another theme for virtuemart and the product page you can check for the stocks available or not. If its not available then you can redirect your page to the where ever you want.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you.